# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode with pyodbc-azure

Tags: python, django, utf-8, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

I use [pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) 1.1.5 to connect my django project to a SQL Server db (aberration, I know)
My client is **SQL Server Native Client 11.0**

When I try to open the corresponding change_list I get this error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte. You passed in 'ESPA\xd1A' (<type 'str'>)
```

The annoying character is Ñ.
I've checked the encoding of my db and I got that is **Modern_Spanish_CI_AS** which, I believe, is equivalent to 'latin1' or 'cp1252'.

I have tried to modify the pyodb\base.py replacing wherever utf-8 appears to cp1252 or latin1 (following tips described in this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=24)), but the error is still referring to utf8.

What else can I do? (other than change the backend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok!
Finally I got it:

```
'unicode_results': True,
```

Adding a new option in Django settings db connection